# php simplexml showing unexpected error

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i'm trying to create a xml file with the following code:

```
$xmlfile='template.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$xml->asXML('12801.xml');
```

while template.xml file contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<posts>
    <1president/>
    <2vice-president/>
    <3secretary/>
    <4assistant-secretary/>
    <5science-secretary/>
    <6dramatic-secretary/>
    <7athletic-secretary/>
</posts>
```

it's throwing a lot of errors saying:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): template.xml:3: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name in try.php on line 3
```

what is the problem here? as much i know, the xml in template.xml seems to be valid.

Comment: Element names are case sensitive. 
 Must begin with letter or underscore(`_`).
 After initial character following are allowed:
 digits
 period(`.`)
 hyphen(`-`)
 underscore(`_`)
 colon(`:` - legal but should not be used except for namespaces
 NO other characters are allowed like #, @, $, %.... http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar

Comment: i created the template.xml file with simplexml only. it didn't show any error at that time.

Comment: Oh, so I'm sorry the w3c RFC for XML is incorrect in its definition, erroneously stating that digits are invalid starct characters for a tag name

Comment: @MarkBaker
dude. no need to be offensive. i've said what i've experienced. i created the template.xml file with following code only which was a success.

`$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post") or die(mysql_error());
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement("<posts></posts>");;
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
 $newchild = $xml->addChild($row3['post']);
$xml->asXML("vote/template.xml");`

Comment: I've explained why your file is invalid, and why it's generating this error: I've provided the link to the relevant W3C recommendation... just because simplexml allows you to create an invalid file doesn't make it any less invalid

Comment: i didn't expected simpleXML having a bug as it's popular. one time it's not checking for validation and the other time it's checking. by the way thanks. i've added an extra 'a' at the beginning while creating the template.

Comment: simplexml is simple, and designed for handling the simplest of xml files: it's not written to handle every last complexity of xml. In fact has problems with anything more than the simplest xml files (e.g. namespaces become incredibly complicated to handle when working with simplexml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML tags cannot start with numbers. It should always start with one of the following characters:

> [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

Something like this should work:

```
<posts>
    <president/>
    <vice-president/>
    <secretary/>
    <assistant-secretary/>
    <science-secretary/>
    <dramatic-secretary/>
    <athletic-secretary/>
</posts>
```

You can easily verify this by using an online XML validator, such as [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).

See the documentation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar